# How I can add and remove the attribute "readonly"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Check City Value
  var city_value = parseInt($("#city").val());
  if( city_value == 0) {
     $("#state").attr("readonly", true);
     //$("#rate").attr("readonly", "readonly");   
  } else {
     $("#state").removeAttr("readonly");
     //document.getElementById("state").removeAttribute("readonly",0);
     //get_states(city_value);
  }
 /***
  //Check State Value
  var state_value = parseInt($('#state').val());
  if( state_value == 0) {
      $('#rate').attr('readonly', true); 
  } else {
     $('#rate').attr('readonly', false);
  }
  ***/
});
```

Here is my sample codes.

```
<td><select name="city" id="city">
<option value="0">PLEASE_SELECT_TEXT</option>
<option value="Antalya">Antalya</option>
<option value="Bodrum">Bodrum</option>
<option value="Istanbul">Istanbul</option>
</select>&nbsp;</td>
<td><div id="states"><input type="text" name="state" value="FORCE_FOR_SELECT" readOnly id="state"></div></td>
```

I've also added doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Your code already does that. Can you please elaborate a *bit* more about the problem? What *actually* happens and what not? If you can, can you please also repost it in flavor of an SSCCE? http://sscce.org Don't forget to include the doctype and tell about the browsers you tried.

Comment: That doesn't work and I really don't know the issue. There is no JavaScript error and no action at the page. And the input type(text) still at "readonly"...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, finally I've found the solution. I've used onChange function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//$(document).ready(function() {
function check_city(city_value) {
  //Check City Value
  city_value = $("#city").val();
  if( city_value == "0") {
     $("#state").attr("readonly", true);
     //$("#rate").attr("readonly", "readonly");   
  } else {
     $("#state").attr("readonly", false);
     //$("#state").removeAttr("readonly");
     //document.getElementById("state").removeAttribute("readonly",0);
     //get_states(city_value);
  }
 /***
  //Check State Value
  var state_value = parseInt($('#state').val());
  if( state_value == 0) {
      $('#rate').attr('readonly', true); 
  } else {
     $('#rate').attr('readonly', false);
  }
  ***/
//});
}
</script>

<td><select name="city" id="city" onChange="check_city(this.value)">
<option selected value="0">PLEASE_SELECT_TEXT</option>
<option value="Antalya">Antalya</option>
<option value="Bodrum">Bodrum</option>
<option value="Istanbul">Istanbul</option>
</select>&nbsp;</td>
<td><div id="states"><input type="text" name="state" value="FORCE_FOR_SELECT" readonly id="state"></div></td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Works fine here in all major browsers I have. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2496443</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#toggle').click(function() {
                    $('#foo').attr('readonly', !$('#foo').attr('readonly'));
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            input[readonly] { 
                background: lightgray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="foo">
        <button id="toggle">toggle readonly</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Toggling it turns the background gray (although not all browsers do that) and the input is uneditable (this is consistent among all webbrowsers). So your problem lies somewhere else. You're probably using a poor [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) and possibly also in combination with a poor webbrowser.

Answer (score 4):

While the `readonly` property takes a boolean value, the `readonly` attribute takes a string value. You should use the code that you have commented out:

```
$("#rate").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: jQuery is smart enough to translate this for you. The same applies to `checked` and so on.

Comment: Regardless of jQuery, that's also dependent on the doctype used. In XHTML you would need to specify the attribute value, while in HTML you don't need to specify any one.

Answer (score 3):

**You can do it in pure JavaScript** (or [Vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636194/4217744)) **without** [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

**Set attribute** `readOnly`:

```
document.getElementById("state").readOnly = true;
```

**and unset**:

```
document.getElementById("state").readOnly = false;
```

**Equivalent** to *object-oriented notation* is also this *array-oriented notation*:

```
document.getElementById("state")['readOnly']
```

**It is also important that in *JavaScript* all the properties are *case sensitive***, so it is important to remember about the large `O` in the `readOnly` property, otherwise it will *not work*...