# Translate simple Jquery to VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this: `$('#night > li').appendTo('#day');`

The code moves all `<li>` elements of `<ul id="night">` to the end of `<ul id="day">`.

Please, how can I translate this into VanillaJS?

**I mean, how do I rewrite the code so I do not need Jquery?**

Have this so far:

document.getElementById('night').li.appendTo.document.getElementById('day');

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs

Comment: You don't need jQuery. jQuery is basically a way of making javascript a bit easier but with a fairly chunky library to do so (another http request to slow down a website). Google "JavaScript tutorials" and get stuck in. jQuery doesn't do anything that you cannot do with JavaScript. **$('#someid') = getElementById('someid')**

Comment: @dwhite.me : "jQuery doesn't do anything that you cannot do with JavaScript"... except write shorter, more readable code :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Fairly irrelevant. Code needs to be interpreted by the browser first, enhance user experience second (including minimising load time as much as possible) and THEN a very distant third be legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could look like so

```
var target = document.getElementById( 'day' );
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll( '#night > li' ), function( li ) {
    day.appendChild( li );
});
```

Comment: typo: car should be var

Answer (score 5):

In pure JavaScript you could do it like this:

```
var night = document.getElementById("night");
var day = document.getElementById("day");
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#night > li");

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
  day.appendChild(lis[i]);
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30p8me48/) for working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var dayUl = document.getElementById("day");
var nightUl = document.getElementById("night");
var nightLis = nightUl.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, len = nightLis.length; i < len; i++) 
{
    dayUl.appendChild(nightLis[i]);
}
```

Also, you can go with @Marcus Ekwall's solution, but keep in mind that the solution isn't fully compatible with IE8 or below, and the first query for the night node is redundant (because below he searches for #night > li)