# Why I can't obtain the value of the value attribute of the option defined into a select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem trying to retrieve the value related to the selected option of a select.

So, into my page I have:

```
<select id="selAttivitaSelezionata" class="form-control valid" name="selAttivita" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="valida">Valida Progetto</option>
    <option value="invalida">Rimuovi Validazione</option>
</select>
```

then I have the following jQuery code that is performed every time that the user select an option inside the previous select:

```
$("#selAttivitaSelezionata").change(function() {
    //alert("TIPOLOGIA PROGETTO CAMBIATA");
                    
    var sel = $("#selAttivitaSelezionata");
    var val = sel.value;
    alert(val);
                    
    $("#statoProgettoLabel").hide();
    $("#selStatoProgetto").hide();
});
```

So, as you can see first I select the **select** object in the DOM having **id="selAttivitaSelezionata"** and then I try to obtain the selected value by **sel.value**, then I print it into an alert popup

The problem is that the alert is empty. Using the FireBug debugger I see that the **sel** variable is correctly initialized but the **val** variable is **undefined** as value obtained by **sel.value**.

Why? What am I missing? How can I obtain the value of the **value attribute** (valida or invalida)?

Comment: The node element `<select ...>` does have a `value` property but, the once that is wrapped in jQuery, you have to use jQuery methods, in this case the `val()` method to retrieve the `value` property or, you could use `this.value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have this:

```
var sel = $('#selAttivitaSelezionata');
```

Which makes `sel` a jQuery object.

This:

```
var val = sel.value;
```

Should be this:

```
var val = sel.val();
```

As [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is the jQuery method for retrieving the value.

You could make this much better by using `$(this)`:

```
$("#selAttivitaSelezionata").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#statoProgettoLabel, #selStatoProgetto").hide();
});
```

Comment: The best would be in this case of a single select element: `this.value`

Comment: Only [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33501540/2025923) explain why `sell.value` doesn't work. :)

Comment: @Tushar: Yes, but yours is the only answer that will confuse people with references to VanillaJS. Not that many people, especially beginners like the OP, know that VanillaJS is really just plain old Javascript. VanillaJS was created as a joke and I don't think it should be used to reference Javascript. What's wrong with saying 'Javascript'? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you're looking for:

```
var val = sel.val();
```

Here is a reference to jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 3):

`sel` is jQuery object, you cannot use Javascript methods on it.

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on it to get the value.

```
sel.val();
```

---

If you want to use Javascript methods,

```
var sel = $("#selAttivitaSelezionata")[0];
var val = sel.value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two elements, instead just use the one along with the `.val()` jQuery function.

**Working example**

```js
$("#selAttivitaSelezionata").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);

  $("#statoProgettoLabel").hide();
  $("#selStatoProgetto").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selAttivitaSelezionata" class="form-control valid" name="selAttivita" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="valida">Valida Progetto</option>
  <option value="invalida">Rimuovi Validazione</option>
</select>
```

- [`.val()` - jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: even with $(this).val(); would work. just a little improvement (i know it's like that on the question)

Comment: Good suggestion, amended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't query the DOM again inside your "change" handler; jQuery gives you a reference to the element (the value of `this`):

```
$("#selAttivitaSelezionata").change(function() {
  var sel = $(this);
  var val = sel.val();

  // ...
});
```