# How to use HTML in a Javascript if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Okay, I am trying to run a code in JavaScript that asks the user if they want to view a video. If they do, then a video would play, if not, then it won't. Basically, I am using an html5 code for the video and I am not sure how to only show the video if the user clicks OK. I am hoping for something along the lines that the video player won't even show up unless they click Okay.

```js
var something = confirm("Want to watch a video?");
if (something) {
  //Run the HTML to play the video
} else {
  alert("Okay.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video width='320' height='240' controls>
    <source src='videolink.mp4'>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

This is a very simple example of what I am trying to do. Anyways, that's it. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as a basis, just play the video if the answer is yes.

Code below, and here is a working demo: **https://jsfiddle.net/q956pbvp/**

**JS**

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo"),
    something = confirm("Want to watch a video?");

if (something) {
  video.play();
} else {
  alert("Okay.");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video width='320' height='240' controls id="myvideo">
    <source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

***NOTE***: There are many other ways you can invoke the video. E.g. you can have it hidden with CSS and in the `if(something)` statement you can "show" it. You can also use AJAX to inject the video to the page only if the user hits Yes. The list goes on.

*Edit:*
Here is another demo (fork) of the code above, but the video is hidden initially, unless the user says yes. https://jsfiddle.net/tjnkgbo7/

Comment: The snippet works, but I am using codecademy.com. For some reason that doesn't work. Is there an alternative website for writing code for free? The code works great.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. JSFiddle link works? But when you copy the code into Code Academy it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I click on the JSFiddle link and it works perfectly. Exactly what I want. But when I paste into Codecademy, it won't play the video unless I push the play button. I'm guessing video.play(); wont work or something for Codecademy.

Comment: Oh wait, I got it. Codecademy uses tabs. The default has a tab for html, one for css, and one for javascript. I pasted the javascript code on the javascript side and the html on the html tab. That did not work. I tried using the <script></script> to run the java code in html and it worked great. Thank you for your help. Both of your answers work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an if/else for this. Just ask the question and give them a button that says "Yes". If they don't want to watch it, they click nothing and the video stays hidden and paused. Using vanilla JS, this will reveal the video when a button with the ID = "myvidbutton" is clicked and call the play() method on the HTML5 video. It also hides the button.

If you want to do a yes and no button, then do the same as below, but add a click handler for the "no" button that does whatever the alternative is.

**HTML**

```
<video id="Video1" width='320' height='240' controls>
    <source src='videolink.mp4'>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<p>Do you want to watch the video?</p>
<button id="myvidbutton">Yes</button>
```

**JS**

```
var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
var playbutton = document.getElementById("myvidbutton");
video.style.display = 'none';

playbutton.onclick = displayVideo();

function displayVideo(){

      video.style.display = 'block';
      playbutton.style.display = 'none';
      video.play();
}
```

Comment: Vanilla JS for the win!

Comment: I feel kind of stupid asking, but what is the script src for vanilla Javascript?

Comment: See http://vanilla-js.com/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs :) But jokes aside, it's another way of saying "no framework", just plain old JavaScript

Comment: Not a stupid question at all @StevenThePig_ . If you are new to web development, "Vanilla JS" would probably throw you. Sorry about that. Vanilla JS is just plain old Javascript without any libraries/frameworks included. In your case, I chose plain old vanilla JS so you didn't have to import jQuery. Was not really necessary for a simple function like you were asking for. A lot of times people will answer you using jQuery - which is perfectly fine if its the right tool for the job. Your question lead me to believe you were new at this, so I wanted to keep it simple for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, and I am new. I am 15 years old actually, just trying to learn for fun. Like I responded to the above responce, the weird thing is, video.play() seems not to work in Codecademy.

Comment: I commented the same thing to the other solution, but I got it to work thank you so much!

Comment: Keep at it, I was about your age when I started. Turn fun into a career.