# Jquery $(window).height() gives wrong value when setting height for document element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So my problem is when i get `$(window).height()` of an empty document it gives the correct value, but when i set a height for the div (`.main-header`) the `$(window).height()` gives it's value plus value close to the div height ,

this picture when i set a `height` 0 for the `.main-header` div

[image]

and this when i set 700px `height` for `.main-header`

[image]

i have tried $(window).load() and $(document).ready() and both gave same value https://jsfiddle.net/nev5onff/

```js
$(window).load(function () {

  var  header = $('.main-header'),
       windowH = $(window).height();
  $('.test').text( windowH);

});
```

```css
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #888;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<header class="main-header"></header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll try and answer the best I can.

**Weave:** *Pure JS*
http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f722c9d64b3e290ec7cc9b4c1a6d19b8

So if you're trying to grab the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) of your window/document you can use... (I'm using [vanilla/plain js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs))

```
var test = document.querySelector('.test');
test.textContent = window.innerHeight;
```

However if you were grabbing the [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) of an element, if it has [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) that sometimes can add to the elements [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) depending on how it's styled regardless if it's height is 0 or auto.

In some cases you may want to use [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) over [`innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) <kbd>[`source`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)</kbd>

```
var test = document.querySelector('.test'),
    mainHeader = document.querySelector('.main-header');

test.innerHTML = test.clientHeight
```

Here's a simple fiddle demonstrating this process.

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.test'),
    mainHeader = document.querySelector('.main-header');

test.innerHTML = test.clientHeight
```

```css
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #888;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<header class="main-header"></header>
```

Comment: Your answer is very useful but i need to get window height to set header height based on it, but when i make that it gives value greater than window height , i appreciate your help.

Comment: The height is correct. I think you might be possibly confusing the default body [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). You could use [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), or  you can do [this little trick](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9c850d05079a1074760798ced6c8d7c9) in CSS with position and margin to fix that.

Comment: thank you very much, the height trick has solved my problem, thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem glad I could help