# Why isn't jQuery finding the div containing display mathematics in this case

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, katex

I'm attempting to construct a minimal working example of KaTeX rendering a bunch of math on a web page. I've put together the following HTML file for this purpose:

```js
$(".inline-math").each(
  function(element) {
    console.log("Rivimatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML, element);
  }
);

$(".display-math").each(
  function(element) {
    console.log("Näyttömatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML, element);
  }
);
```

```html
<p>Tässä on näyttömuotoinen yhtälö:</p>
<div class="display-math">
  F(b) - F(a) = \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
```

The mathematics is not being rendered, but KaTeX was downloaded successfully, so that is not the cause:

[image: KaTeX downloaded successfully.]

However, jQuery is not discovering the actual elements containing the math:
[image]

Why is this? I'd expect the `div` containing the math to be printed to console at least. Why isn't it beign printed, though?

P.S.

I'm not using the automatic rendering feature provided by the addon just yet. I want to get this working on a very basic level, before I complicate things more.

Comment: It was the `defer` in the script attrivbutes that was postponing the retrieval and/or execution of the katex-script. I need to modify the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

It's simply you are using jQuery's [`$(selector).each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function incorrectly.

From the documentation:

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )

Instead of following the native [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) implementation, jQuery's `.each`'s callback function will have **index** as *first* argument, and **element** as *second* argument.

What you need to do is simply:

```
$(".display-math").each(
  function(i, element) {
    // ----^ -^
    console.log("Näyttömatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML,element);
  }
);
```

Or, you can just use [VanillaJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.display-math').forEach(function(element){
    console.log("Näyttömatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML,element);
});
```

## Working Code

```js
$(".inline-math").each(
  function(i, element) {
    console.log("Rivimatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML, element);
  }
);

$(".display-math").each(
  function(i, element) {
    console.log("Näyttömatikkaa: " + element.innerHTML);
    katex.render(element.innerHTML, element);
  }
);
```

```html
<p>Tässä on näyttömuotoinen yhtälö:</p>
<div class="display-math">
  F(b) - F(a) = \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
```