# What is the difference between Vue JS and React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have started studying Vue Js and React Js, I searched on google could not find satisfactory answers for comparison between both.

I found What is Vue js and another Question What is React Js. But there is no question which gives the comparison of both.

Comment: "vanilla JS" is not a framework.

Comment: If a website told you that, that website is wrong. It is not a framework.

Comment: [What is VanillaJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653) and [What is Vue.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+vue+js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is VanillaJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs)

Comment: @ponury-kostek — Vanilla JS isn't pure JavaScript. It includes all the browser supplied APIs like DOM and localStorage.

Comment: @Quentin so I can't use Vanilla JS in Node.js? In Node.js there is no DOM or localStorage

Comment: Wikipedia quote `The terms Vanilla JavaScript and Vanilla JS refer to JavaScript not extended by any frameworks or additional libraries. Scripts written in Vanilla JS are plain JavaScript code.`

Comment: @ponury-kostek — It's a pointless buzzword referring to the absence of stuff. Not a "thing" you can use.

Comment: @ponury-kostek — If that Wikipedia quote was correct then you couldn't use the DOM API that browsers supply.

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thank you, now i do understand about Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla JS is a term used to mean "Not using any third party libraries / frameworks at all", just what is provided by the host environment.

Vue JS is a framework for building SPAs.

---

> well on their website you see "Vanilla JS is a fast, lightweight, cross-platform framework for building incredible, powerful JavaScript applications"

[This website](http://vanilla-js.com/)? That sentence is a joke.