# html text area show set span value

Tags: javascript, html

In my html, I have a text area and input area.

my jquery is trying to set some value to the span element.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <span data-name="sstNumber" class="sstNumber">
        <textarea class="wt-resize" maxlength="50"  rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
    </span>
    <br>
</div>
```

when i do `document.querySelector('[data-name="sstNumber"]').textContent = "value";` the text area border dissappears.   How do i show the value and the text border doesn't dissapear?

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" name="sstnum" value="" size="20">
    <span data-name="sstNumber2" class="sstNumber2"></span>
    <br>
</div>
```

when i do `document.querySelector('[data-name="sstNumber2"]').textContent = "value2";` the value goes outside the box. How do i show the value in the box?

Comment: Do you want to change the value of the textarea and the input field?

Comment: yes. i want to change value by setting the spam element value

Comment: @Jacel you can't target the span to do that, you have to target the textarea _within_ the relevant span. See Jerodev's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of a textarea or an input field, you have to target the element directly and set the `value` attribute.

Like so:

```js
document.querySelector('span[data-name="sstNumber"] textarea').value = "value";
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <span data-name="sstNumber" class="sstNumber">
        <textarea class="wt-resize" maxlength="50"  rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
    </span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Also, you are not using jQuery, this is [vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs).

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the value to the wrong element. You simply need to target the actual `textarea` element if you don't want the `textarea` to disappear.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea.wt-resize').value = "value";
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <span data-name="sstNumber" class="sstNumber">
        <textarea class="wt-resize" maxlength="50"  rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
    </span>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem with the disappearing border is, that you actually overwrite the content of your span element with :

```
document.querySelector('[data-name="sstNumber"]').textContent = "value";
```

Since your textarea is a child element of your span element, you overwrite your textarea. To fix that, put the textarea outside the span element:

```
 <span data-name="sstNumber" class="sstNumber"></span>
 <textarea class="wt-resize" maxlength="50"  rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
```

If you want to change the value of the input element you need to select that element and not the span element :

```
document.querySelector('[name="sstnum"]').value = "value2";
```