# Are Javascript popup boxes (Alert, confirm and prompt) part of 'document' or part of 'Browser' (Client)

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, autoplay

First of all I apologies if am not aware of similar questions been answered, if so please enlighten me so I can refer and learn (In case they satisfy context of my problem).

So, context is my question is completely based on [Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). Right now this policy imposed to take down unwanted stuff or advertisements to be auto played without user's consent. Possibly causing security threats and bandwidth consumption specially on mobile devices.

The only solution to make it work for some legitimate use is to make user interact with website. That's cool, I tried to accomplish this by showing an 'alert' box, but it is not satisfying that criteria (Make user interact first). Rather if I add a button to the document body and click on it, then the criteria match I can listen the audio I want to play on page load.

So I wonder whether these boxes are alien to DOM ? or do they belongs to client only?

I appreciate in advance for any solution which could have been obvious, pro, immature or lay man's knowledge for me to realize. I am a learner.

Comment: They're a part of the environment, ex. browser, you can find them being a part of [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert).

Comment: @Teem thank you for your quick response, I will consider is as answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JavaScript is Client-Side, the [popup boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) are part of the browser (= environment). That is why the `alert()` function's complete name is `window.alert()`. They are not part of the DOM.

Comment: `Javascript is client-side`, Node.js disagrees.

Comment: I assumed we were talking about plain JS

Comment: @JeremyThille The context was with plain JS. Thank you for making a server side point, much Appreciated.

Comment: What do you guys mean "plain JS"?

Comment: A Vanilla JS. This question has answers for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs