# Remove readonly attribute from all input box using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple input text boxs all are by default read-only.

I want to Remove readonly attribute for all the input element within my form instead of particular element, i dont have any idea that with the jQuery how i can select all input and remove the readonly attributes if are added.

**Html :**

```
<input type="text" name="fistname" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="lastname" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="emailaddres" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="password" readonly="true">
<input type="button" name="edit" id="edit">
```

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).on("click","#edit",function(e){
         // What should i do here..?
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('input').removeAttr('readonly')` https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496443/how-i-can-add-and-remove-the-attribute-readonly

Comment: @JohnR , i guess removing readonly attribute for an individual input element and within an entire form is a different thing  with selecting all the inputs using jQuery! He might not have an idea that how to select all the inputs of a form using jQuery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the properties

```
$(':input').prop('readonly', false)
```

*OR*, Use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method

```
$(':input').removeAttr('readonly')
```

References

- [:input Selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method like following.

```
$(document).on("click","#edit",function(e){
    $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('readonly');

    //$(':input').removeAttr('readonly'); //if want to select all types of form controls
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.canEdit').attr('readonly', false);
```

and add a class to all input elements you wants to allow user available to edit;

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#edit').click(function (){
   $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('readonly');
});
```